# Make every collectionview cell a different color upon click based on order clicked

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want the color of the first selected cell in my collection view to correspond with the first color in an array, next selected cell to correspond with the second color in the array, etc. Which means I have an array

```
let colorArray:[UIColor] = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.green, UIColor.red]
```

I want the first selected cell blue, next green, next red. If I unselect two of the three cells, they are no longer colored and the next selected cell would be green.

I know there are a bunch of ways to do it, but I'm setting the background color through the setting of the isHighlighted property of the cell, so I need the color to be passed to the cell before the highlighted property is set. The method didSelectItemAt is called after the property is set so it isn't working.

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {

        didSet  {

            if isHighlighted {
                //set background color here
            }
```

It would be best if there was a comparable method to willSelectAtPath like with tableview cells, but all I've found is shouldSelectItemAt and it isn't called before the highlighted property is set.

Right now I'm looping through all visible cells and setting their current color property to the current active color, but that seems cumbersome.

Comment: I would create a UICollectionViewCell subclass, and have a property of `color`. Then in `cellForItemAt indexPath` delegate method set that cell's color. Then simply use that color in your `isHighlighted` override

Comment: The problem is any cell could be any of the colors from the array depending on the order it is selected. The third cell in the collection view could be blue if selected first as could the 8th cell in the view if it is selected first, which means each cell would have to be continuously updated after each additional cell is selected